Apache Camel route only working once on startup
I've been working with Apache Camel and Quarkus to create a route that returns the file count from a directory on an SFTP server. The route works fine the first time I run the program, as it correctly returns the file count in the directory (5 files), but only once. After that, I need to restart the program because it returns 0 every time I try to get the file count again. As I mentioned, this issue is resolved by restarting the program. Any ideas on how to fix this behavior?
this is my current route:
    from("direct:fileCount")
    .setHeader("binaryFlag", constant(1))
    .setProperty("fileCounter", constant(0))
    .loopDoWhile(simple("${header.binaryFlag} == 1"))

        .pollEnrich("sftp://user@192.000.00.00/uploads?password=password123&noop=true&include=.*",1000)

        .choice()
            .when(body().isNotNull())
                .process(exchange -> {                     
                        Integer currentCount = exchange.getProperty("fileCounter", Integer.class);
                        exchange.setProperty("fileCounter", currentCount + 1);
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader("binaryFlag", 1); //Keep the loop alive
                    })
                    
            .endChoice()
            
            .otherwise() 
                .process(exchange -> 
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("binaryFlag", 0)//Kills the loop  
                )
                .endChoice()

        .end()  
    .end()
    .process(exchange -> {
         Integer finalCount = exchange.getProperty("fileCounter", Integer.class);
         exchange.getIn().setBody("fileCount: " + finalCount);
    }) ; 

I expose the route via REST
           rest(urlBase)
            .get("getFileCount")
            .produces("application/json")
            .to("direct:fileCount");


Not sure, if it's possible with Camel. As you use noop=true, the camel route is automatically setting idempotent=true so that the route will NOT consume the same files again, which is what you actually want to achieve. Maybe you can play around with a custom idempotentRepository and try to empty it, when you access the REST endpoint

What happens if you drop a file into the directory?  Do you get a 1 back?
